# Changing image/css if scalar variable > 0, Perl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, perl

I have a header with a notification system implemented with an integer next to a `mail1.png` like so:

```
<div class = "header">
     <a class="notifications-dropdown-trigger"><b id="num-posts"><%= (scalar @post_regular) %></b> <img src="/images/icons/mail1.png" /></a>
</div>
```

the `scalar @post_regular` retrieves and shows the amount of notifications in the database for that user as an integer.

I want to implement something that will change the image next to it, as well as the background color of the number, whenever the `scalar @post_regular` is greater than 0. So when the user has at least one notification, I want the image next to it to display `mail2.png` instead of `mail1.png` and the background color to be `red` instead of the default.

I'm assuming this approach should be tackled with javascript? I'm not too familiar with it and not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add logic to your img src:

```
<img src="/images/icons/mail<%= @post_regular ? 2 : 1 %>.png" />
```

Similar functionality can be used to adjust the styling, but I'd probably recommend injecting a secondary class to set the background color instead of hardcoding the style.

Comment: Can you explain the `?2:1` functionality to me. I've never used that before and just started Perl recently. Also, can I use words instead of `2:1` like `<img src="/images/icons/mail<%= @post_regular ? closed : open %>.png" />`

Comment: Ternary "?:" is the [conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator), just as in C. It works much like an if-then-else.  Also, you could use words as the returned values, as long as you enclosed them in quotes and therefore treated them as strings.

Comment: everything makes sense and works perfectly, thank you